# What was my friend doing?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, no-computers

I asked my friend what he did last week and he gave me this note.

> - ivoesfe ivoesfe ivoesfe
> - hppe nfo hppe nfo
> - uif tjohjoh sbjo
> - pof gmfx
>   dvdlppt oftu
> - qbbnfsjdbosjt
> - nvujoz
>   cpvouz
> - tbqmbdfvo

**What was my friend doing?**

Comment: Is this a cipher? Or an anagram?

Comment: it's a cipher. @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: Your friend was ... being a jerk. Why couldn't he just tell you what he was doing instead of  wasting his time and yours on silly ciphers? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a

> ROT-1 cipher:
>
>  - hundred hundred hundred
>  - good men good men
>  - the singing rain 
>  - one flew
>    cuckoos nest
>  - paamericanris
>  - mutiny
>    bounty
>  - saplaceun

---

Now we just have to make sense of this:

> Credit to [C. Woods](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26811) for [noting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/what-was-my-friend-doing/45147#comment136009_45147) this is a rebus where the answers are movie titles: (and also providing all solutions)
>  1. 300
>  2. A Few Good Men
>  3. Singing in the Rain
>  4. One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest
>  5. American in Paris
>  6. Mutiny on the Bounty
>  7. A Place in the Sun

---

So the final answer is

> He was watching the movies listed above

Comment: These look like those rebus puzzles, where each answer is a movie title:
1. 300
2. A Few Good Men
3. Singing in the Rain
4. One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest
5. American in Paris
6. Mutiny on the Bounty.
7. A Place in the Sun

Comment: 'One flew' above 'Cukoos Nest' = one flew over the cukoos nest

Comment: @C.Woods Seems like that's the solution. You can either post an answer for this or I can just make my post a community wiki and you can edit it in. Let me know :P

Comment: If you'd like you can just edit it into your post yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your friend was:

> Watching movies?

@LukasRotter worked out it was a ROT-1 cipher for

> It's just a ROT-1 cipher:
>
> - hundred hundred hundred
> - good men good men
> - the singing rain
> - one flew
>     cuckoos nest
> - paamericanris
> - mutiny
>     bounty
> - saplaceun

These are rebuses for movie titles:

Ones I've worked out:

> - [300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/300_(film)) (three hundreds)
> - [A few good men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Few_Good_Men) (a couple of 'good men')
> - [Singing in the rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain) (singing inbetween the and rain)
> - [One flew over the cuckoos nest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Flew_Over_the_Cuckoo%27s_Nest_(film)) ('One flew' above 'cuckoos  nest')
> - [Mutiny on the Bounty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutiny_on_the_Bounty_(1962_film)) (Mutiny on 'Bounty')

@LukasRotter got the rest:

> - [An American in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_American_in_Paris_(film))  ('American' in 'Paris')
> - [A Place in the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Place_in_the_Sun_(film)) ('A place' in 'sun')