# It's my weird friend

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rhyme

My [weird friend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45146/31384) is back. He asked me to guess a number. Then instead of waiting for me to guess like a normal person, he handed me a piece of paper with this written on it:

> You thought this clue was the toughest one.
>   (Not by a long shot.)
>   But this riddle isn't even half done.
>   (Nope, definitely not.)
>   You see the times are getting tough.
>   (I've said that twice.)
>   Four of my coworkers told me that they had had enough.
>   (Isn't that nice?)
>   There is a five percent chance this riddle will end soon.
>   (Better go throw the dice.)
>   Ninety-five says the end of June.
>   (When temperatures melt the ice.)
>   Anyways, I need to go back to watching 300 the movie.
>   (Like right now.)
>   So if you could solve this quickly, that would be groovy.
>   (Very much wow.)

Scratched on the back of the page was the number 86415690.
**What number is my friend thinking of?**

Note: the obvious answer isn't always right.

Comment: 86415690 perhaps?

Comment: And I don't think the tags are unconventional at all

Comment: Okay I'll take it out of the challenge, but leave the question

Comment: Oh definetely leave the question!

Comment: Well, there are 8 verbal hints (not counting parentheses) and 8 digits in the number. June (the sixth month) occurs in the sixth verbal hint which is also the sixth digit in the number. That's all I got so far. Interesting!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

He's (maybe) thinking of

> 6

---

Taking the number **86415690** to mean...

> The position of a word in each of the lines not in parentheses.
>
>  There are 8 digits in the number and 8 lines in the riddle. The 8th (first digit) word of the first line is "one" which already fits so well this could be the obvious answer that's not always right.

---

> The words are...
>
>   8: one
>   6: half
>   4: times
>   1: four
>   5: percent
>   6: of  (or arguably "June")
>   9: 300
>   0:
>
>   1/2 * 300 * 4/100 = **6**

Comment: Can't think of any more compelling reasoning!